# Can spring fill a list of a specific type automatically?

Tags: java, spring, list, autowired

I would like to have a list filled by elements of a specific type automatically by Spring injection.

```
@Component
class Scratch {
 @Autowired
 List<Person> person;
}
```

Given are these beans:

```
@Configuration
class App {

  @Bean
  public Person coolPerson() {
   return new CoolPerson();
  }

  @Bean
  public Person stupidPerson() {
    return new stupidPerson();
  }

  @Bean
  public Person funnyPerson() {
    return new FunnyPerson();
  }

}
```

The result I like to have is that the `List<Person>` is filled with three elements. One of the declared `Bean`s of the `Configuration` above.

If this is not possible through Spring's DI is there mybe a hacky way?

I think spring is kind of collecting all `Bean`s in it's context. So what about having access to this context and filling the list a bit more manually like:

**Pseudo**

```
    @Component
    class Scratch {
      List<Person> person = SpringContext.getBeans(Person.class);
    }
```

Comment: You've written all the code - why not try it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this works:

```
@Component
public class Scratch {
    @Autowired
    List<Person> person;
}
```

That will inject every instance of `Person`.

You can even autowire in a `List<MyInterface>` and it'll inject all instances of that interface that it can find.